# PCIe add-on Wi-Fi adapter as receiver + repeater

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-access-point, ad-hoc-network, repeater

I am aware of Windows' Hosted Network capability :

- Sets up a network as an AP
- Can coexist with an existing Wi-Fi network

Also bridging :

- two networks share address space

And access points in a single network

- Wireless clients can roam seamlessly from one AP to another for best signal strength

Combining all the above :
My desktop is in a corner of the house. As wiring it up is going to be difficult, it's currently on WiFi through a PCIe adapter. I plan to wire it up sometime, but until then... The quality of the connection is not too bad. My mobile though has bigger problems with the signal.

Can I use my desktop WiFi card as a wireless repeater? That is, it should appear to the mobile as an AP of the same network. I am currently able to set up a hosted network with the same SSID as the network it is also connected to as a client. But internet is not available on the phone : DHCP etc. is not configured to "passthrough".

I know this is not ideal for speed, but I'm never using both the desktop and the phone on the internet at the same time.

Comment: You do understand every repeater you use will decrease possible throughput by a certain amount right?  What 802.11 mode are we talking about?

Comment: Yeah, but this will be the only repeater. Using 802.11n